# get phone or external memory storage path of windows phone in phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, phonegap-plugins

I am using **phonegap to download file from server** and save it in **phone or external memory** using file plugin and my code is

```
cordova.file.documentsDirectory for IOS
```

and

```
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory for Android
```

But when i deploy my app in windows phone its shows error.

Can anyone help me to get the storage path of phone or external memory to save the file for Windows Phone.

Thanks in advance.